# Client authentication failed in Postman request for Amazon Alexa Smart Home Skill LWA

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, postman, alexa-skills-kit

I am referring to [Amazon documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smarthome/authenticate-a-customer-permissions.html#enable-testing-for-the-skill) for the purpose of Customer Authentication. Currently, I am using LWA.

Steps I followed:

1. I enabled the Send Alexa Events Permission from the Alexa developer Console in Build > Permission page.
2. I took the grant code from the request in the cloudwatch logs which was sent when I logged in using Alexa companion app.

Example:-

```
    {
     "directive": {
         "header": {
             "messageId": "Example",
             "name": "AcceptGrant",
             "namespace": "Alexa.Authorization",
             "payloadVersion": "3"
         },
         "payload": {
            "grant": {
                "code": "Example2",
                "type": "OAuth2.AuthorizationCode"
            },
            "grantee": {
                "token": "Example3",
                "type": "BearerToken"
            }
         }
      }
    }
```

3. Permission Page under build on Alexa Developer console gave me client-Id and client-secret Which I used for making the post request to https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token.

Example:-

```
 POST /auth/o2/token HTTP/l.l
 Host: api.amazon.com
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 
 grant_type=authorization_code&code=&client_id=&client_secret=
```

I passed the code,client_id, and client_secret in the above example and made the post request to this URL https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token

4. I tried using x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 and also JSON for the Content-Type.

I followed the step given in the above documentation and I am stuck on the error ( 401 Unauthorized ):

```
{
    "error_description": "The request has an invalid grant parameter : code",
    "error": "invalid_grant"
}
```

I tried implementing it using Python code and Postman both. Ending up with the Same above error scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code to help you and others who are looking to send events to alexa gateway.

```js
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-1'});
    
    // Create the DynamoDB service object
    const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: 'latest' });
    const doc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
                convertEmptyValues: true,
                service: ddb
            });        
    
    // Using 'request' for http POST and GET request.
    // https://www.npmjs.com/package/requests
    // npm install --save requests 
    const r = require('request');

    //Handle Authorization. Call this method from your lambda handler whenever you get Alexa.Authorization message. You will get this message only when you select permission to 
    //send events in your Smart Home Skill.
    //Access to Event gateway allows you to enable Proactive Device Discovery and 
    //Proactive State Reporting in your skill
    //More information on Alexa.Authorization can be found on https://developer.amazon.com/docs/device-apis/alexa-authorization.html
    function handleAuthorization(request, context, user) {  
    
        //Even when you are using your own authentication, the url below will still
        //point to amazon OAuth token url. The token you obtain here has to be stored
        //separately for this user. Whenever sending an event to alexa event gateway you will
        //require this token.
        //URL below is for EU server. Look at following documentation link to identify correct url
        //for your system.
        //https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smarthome/send-events-to-the-alexa-event-gateway.html
        var url = "https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token";
        var body = {
            grant_type : 'authorization_code',
            code : request.directive.payload.grant.code,
            client_id : 'your client id from permissions page on developer portal where you enable alexa events. This is id different than one you specify in account linking settings',
            client_secret : 'client secret from permissions page'
        }
        
        //https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smarthome/authenticate-a-customer-permissions.html
        r.post({
          url:     url,
          form :  body
        }, function(error, response, b){    
            if (error) { return console.log(error); }
            var body = JSON.parse(b);
            var params = {
              TableName: 'Devices',
              Item: {
                'id' : user,
                'auth_token' : body.access_token,
                'refresh_token' : body.refresh_token
              }
            }
            log("DEBUG:", "Authorization Body", JSON.stringify(body));
            log("DEBUG:", "Authorization Response", JSON.stringify(response));
            log("DEBUG:", "Database Params", JSON.stringify(params));
            
            // Call DynamoDB to add the item to the table
            var putObjectPromise = doc.put(params).promise();
            //Store auth_token and refresh_token in database. We will need these
            //while sending events to event gateway.
            //Send a success response.
            putObjectPromise.then(function(data) {
                var response = {
                  event: {
                    header: {
                      messageId: request.directive.header.messageId,
                      namespace: "Alexa.Authorization",
                      name: "AcceptGrant.Response",
                      payloadVersion: "3"
                    },
                    "payload": {
                    }
                  }
                };
        
                context.succeed(response);
            }).catch(function(err) {
                //TODO - Add a Authorization error response JSON here.      
                console.log(err);
            });                         
        });                   
    }
```

Comment: Correct. It is important that you get the client_id and client_secret from the Permissions page. You find the permission page in the Alexa Developer Console (Build -> Tools -> Permissions) . On the permission page the client id and client secret is at the very bottom in the section "Alexa Skill Messaging" (Alexa Client Id, Alexa Client Secret). The "Alexa Skill Messaging" section is only shown when you enable the permission "Send Alexa Events"